# Receiving StackOverFlow Exception at ResolverTextDirection in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I Have a Strange Problem With my ListView, I am Using it for in my chat adapter, its Mainview is very deep but most of their visibility's are gone, so basicly its not that deep, how ever i am using a Spannable String Builder to Filter my chat, here is its code :

```
private static final Factory spannableFactory = Spannable.Factory
        .getInstance();

        private static final Map<Pattern, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<Pattern, Integer>();

        static {
            System.out.println("Adding Patterns");
        addPattern(emoticons, ":)", R.drawable.ic_beer);
        addPattern(emoticons, ":-)", R.drawable.ic_file);
        addPattern(emoticons,":O",R.drawable.antartica10);
        // ...
        }

        private static void addPattern(Map<Pattern, Integer> map, String smile,
        int resource) {
        map.put(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(smile)), resource);
        }

        public static boolean addSmiles(Context context, Spannable spannable) {
        boolean hasChanges = false;
        for (Entry<Pattern, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
        Matcher matcher = entry.getKey().matcher(spannable);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            boolean set = true;
            for (ImageSpan span : spannable.getSpans(matcher.start(),
                    matcher.end(), ImageSpan.class))
                if (spannable.getSpanStart(span) >= matcher.start()
                        && spannable.getSpanEnd(span) <= matcher.end())
                    spannable.removeSpan(span);
                else {
                    set = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (set) {
                hasChanges = true;
                spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, entry.getValue()),
                        matcher.start(), matcher.end(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
        }
        return hasChanges;
        }

        public static Spannable getSmiledText(Context context, CharSequence text) {
        Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
        addSmiles(context, spannable);
        return spannable;
        }
```

Here is my XML of the Fragment Which Holds the ListView:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewchat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/form"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"

    >

</ListView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/message_bar" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TextFeild"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.13"
            android:background="@drawable/message_field"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Write here"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textFieldColor" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SendText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/ImportFile"
             android:layout_width="41dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_margin="5sp"
             android:background="@drawable/send_button"
             android:paddingBottom="5sp"
             android:paddingLeft="15sp"
             android:paddingRight="15sp"
             android:paddingTop="5sp"
             android:text="F"
             android:textColor="#FFF" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/single_chat_record"
             android:layout_width="41dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_margin="5sp"
             android:background="@drawable/send_button"
             android:paddingBottom="5sp"
             android:paddingLeft="15sp"
             android:paddingRight="15sp"
             android:paddingTop="5sp"
             android:text="R"
             android:textColor="#FFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/MSGTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/VideoFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_solid_light_holo">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/videodismiss"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back" 
        android:gravity="bottom"
        />

</FrameLayout>
 </FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout 

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/audioframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_solid_light_holo"
        android:visibility="gone"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#75000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trackTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/trackInitialValue"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:visibility="visible" 
                android:textSize="15sp"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#5033ff33" />





            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/singlechat_musicplayer_artist_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/artist24" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trackArtist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/artistInitialValue"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:visibility="visible" 
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/singlechat_musicplayer_album_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/album24" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trackAlbum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/albumInitialValue"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/songprogressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_full" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/header_bg100"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trackDuration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/durationInitialValue"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trackPostionSeparator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/trackDuration"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/trackDuration"
                android:text="@string/trackPostionSeparator"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trackCurrPostion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/trackPostionSeparator"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/trackDuration"
                android:text="@string/currPositionInitialValue"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/playButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/play"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/play96" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/separator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/separator" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
                    <Button
android:id="@+id/audiodismiss"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:text="Back"
android:layout_gravity="right" 

/>


        </FrameLayout>



    </FrameLayout>
```

the VideoPlayer and MusicPlayer Layers Are Invisible. the Problem i have is some Times at Pressing back Button or When Returning from Back to the Application , i get This Error :

```
  09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at    
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at   
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.resolveTextDirection(View.java:13939)
09-20 05:52:19.019: E/AndroidRuntime(4934):     at 
android.view.View.getResolvedTextDirection(View.java:13923)
```

actually i found out that the Upcoming and DownGoing animation of IME keyboard Causes the problem, but still not solution . Is there Some Thing Wrong with it or problem is Some Where Else?

Comment: i guess it may be beacuase the while loop is not exiting

Comment: if u mean while (matcher.find()) { , it exists